# pandas type object 'Categorical' has no attribute 'from_array'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is my code:

```
df['CabinCat'] = pd.Categorical.from_array(df.Cabin.fillna('0').apply(lambda x: x[0])).codes
```

My target is to fill 0 for the missing value first, then extract the first character only, finally using the codes to convert to numerical values. But I got the below error:

> df['CabinCat'] =
> pd.Categorical.from_array(df.Cabin.fillna('0').apply(lambda x:
> x[0])).codes AttributeError: type object 'Categorical' has no
> attribute 'from_array'

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `from_array`? something like `pd.Categorical(df.Cabine...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Categorical.from_array` was [deprecated in v0.19.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.19.0.html) and finally [removed in v0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.23.0.html)

You can create the categorical codes in this case normally, using the `.str` accessor to get the first character after filling.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.__version__
#'1.2.2'

s = pd.Series([np.NaN, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'hello'])

pd.Categorical(s.fillna('0').str[0]).codes
#array([0, 2, 1, 1, 3], dtype=int8)
```